# Editting a XML file in Excel, then exporting it back as XML

Tags: excel, xml

Is it possible to recover the original XML file after importing it to Excel, even if no changes are made to it?

If I right click the table generated after importing it and then go to `XML -> Export...` I get the error *"Cannot save or export XML data. The XML maps in this workbook are not exportable"*.

Google suggests that some valid XML files can't be exported by Excel. I may be missing something, since I wasn't able to export even this sample XML below, which I've got from Excel internal help page.

**Edit**
Ok, I'm convinced this can't be done with Excel's native resources from the interface. But can it be done with VBA? How?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Root>
  <EmployeeInfo>
    <Name>Jane Winston</Name>
    <Date>2001-01-01</Date>
    <Code>0001</Code>
  </EmployeeInfo>
  <ExpenseItem>
    <Date>2001-01-01</Date>
    <Description>Airfare</Description>
    <Amount>500.34</Amount>
  </ExpenseItem>
  <ExpenseItem>
    <Date>2001-01-01</Date>
    <Description>Hotel</Description>
    <Amount>200</Amount>
  </ExpenseItem>
  <ExpenseItem>
    <Date>2001-01-01</Date>
    <Description>Taxi Fare</Description>
    <Amount>100.00</Amount>
  </ExpenseItem>
  <ExpenseItem>
    <Date>2001-01-01</Date>
    <Description>Long Distance Phone Charges</Description>
    <Amount>57.89</Amount>
  </ExpenseItem>
  <ExpenseItem>
    <Date>2001-01-01</Date>
    <Description>Food</Description>
    <Amount>82.19</Amount>
  </ExpenseItem>
  <ExpenseItem>
    <Date>2001-01-02</Date>
    <Description>Food</Description>
    <Amount>17.89</Amount>
  </ExpenseItem>
  <ExpenseItem>
    <Date>2001-01-02</Date>
    <Description>Personal Items</Description>
    <Amount>32.54</Amount>
  </ExpenseItem>
  <ExpenseItem>
    <Date>2001-01-03</Date>
    <Description>Taxi Fare</Description>
    <Amount>75.00</Amount>
  </ExpenseItem>
  <ExpenseItem>
    <Date>2001-01-03</Date>
    <Description>Food</Description>
    <Amount>36.45</Amount>
  </ExpenseItem>
  <ExpenseItem>
    <Date>2001-01-03</Date>
    <Description>New Suit</Description>
    <Amount>750.00</Amount>
  </ExpenseItem>
</Root>
```